# Deploying Python application depending on C/C++ extensions to offline server

Tags: redhat, python, deployment

I want to deploy a Python application to a RHEL 7.4 server which does not have Internet access. This Python application uses the libraries Pandas and Numpy (among others), which depend on C/C++ extensions that need to be compiled for each platform. I could compile them on the server, but doing this each time I deploy my application takes a lot of time and I want to avoid having to install compilers and other development tools on a production server. I do not have access to an identical server where I can precompile the libraries before deploying the application in production.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Just install the appropriate Python packages on the machine, if that's what you intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

Build a RPM package (packages) on an internet-connected machine that includes everything you need, get the rpm files  to the machine and install.